# I've installed Yarn at a global level. Why can't I see run yarn -v at a project level?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

New to Yarn and I've installed it at global level `npm install -g yarn`

At `~` I can run `yarn -v` and see the version number fine.

However, when I `cd` into my project (currently just an empty folder on the desktop) and run `yarn -v` I get `yarn: command not found`.

Wouldn't having installed it globally allow me to run Yarn anywhere?

Comment: What's your shells `$PATH`?

Comment: Did you try to open a new shell? Maybe that shell was already opened before installation and it did not get the $PATH update while installation.